# Submit custom Wordpress Editor to wp-admin/post.php

Tags: php, wordpress, post, request, editor

I'm trying to get a working post editor on a custom theme page. The editor itself works (using `wp_editor()`), but If I add `action="/wp-admin/post.php"` to the form and the following hidden fields:

`_wpnonce` (`wp_create_nonce()`), `post_type`, `originalaction`, `post_author`, ... the post.php page says `Are you sure you want to do this?`.
If I only send the content I'm being redirect to `wp-admin/edit.php` but no post is being created...

So my question is; is it possible to make a custom wordpress editor submitting to the existing wp-admin/post.php, or do I have to catch the content and uploads and create the post via PHP myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and solved it as following: The form targets my theme's main page, and I handled the form data manually in my `functions.php` (`index.php` would of course work as well):

```
$post_options = array(
    'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['post_title']),
    'post_content'  => $_POST['post_content'],
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_author'   => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_category' => []
);

$new_post = wp_insert_post($post_options);

if (!is_wp_error($new_post)) {
     // success
}
```